# Variation of 5-dimensional Lagrangian-density for 5D Einstein-Gauss-Bonnet gravity

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, variational-calculus

How can I derive equation (2a) and (2b) by variation of the fundamental fundamental five-dimensional Lagrangian density (1) with respect to the connection and the vielbein as mentioned in [arXiv:2109.10388](https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.10388)

[image]